# Show notification with upload progress using Alamofire multipart

Tags: ios, swift, file-upload, background, alamofire

I need to upload multiple files (images, docs etc.) to the server, so I decided to use `Alamofire` for multipart request.

Naturally, that is a time consuming operation and should be accomplished in background so my question is: how to do that properly?
I need a progress update and event when upload is finished.

I searched Google but very few posts give any information. Usually to use `URLSession` but without proper sample related to `Alamofire` or similar libraries.

Answer (score 0):

I believe Alamofire has some built in functions to help with this. Check out the documentation and example they provide here:

https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire/blob/master/Documentation/Usage.md#upload-progress

*Edit: Adding example code.*

I have not tested the following, but I can get you close to where you would like to be. I would assume you need to make sure that you have the background fetching capability enabled as well as maybe the external accessory communication maybe.

[Background Modes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XmxuL.png)

Networking.swift

```
    import Foundation
import Alamofire

class Networking {
    static let sharedInstance = Networking()
    public var sessionManager: Alamofire.SessionManager // Use this for most calls
    public var backgroundSessionManager: Alamofire.SessionManager // Use this for background calls
    private init() {
        self.sessionManager = Alamofire.SessionManager(configuration: URLSessionConfiguration.default)
        self.backgroundSessionManager = Alamofire.SessionManager(configuration: URLSessionConfiguration.background(withIdentifier: "com.youApp.identifier.backgroundtransfer"))
    }
}

let backgroundManager = Networking.sharedInstance.backgroundSessionManager
```

ViewController.swift

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.


    backgroundManager.upload(multipartFormData: { multipartFormData in
        multipartFormData.append(unicornImageURL, withName: "unicorn")
        multipartFormData.append(rainbowImageURL, withName: "rainbow")
    },
         to: "https://httpbin.org/post",
         encodingCompletion: { encodingResult in
            switch encodingResult {
            case .success(let upload, _, _):
                upload.responseJSON { response in
                    debugPrint(response)
                    // Show local notification success here
                }
            case .failure(let encodingError):
                print(encodingError)
                // Show local notification failure here
            }
    })
}
```

Comment: I read that, it's simple to use, but how to show progress in notification? Event when upload is finished? Info which file is uploading? Not so simple..